# Android activity not found in android manifest

Tags: android

Trying to open an activity, the debugger launches en exception:

```
11-29 14:54:02.750: E/AndroidRuntime(26008): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.solinpromex.casajuventudtrescantos/com.solinpromex.casajuventudtrescantos.Calendario_Agenda_Activity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

But I think the mentioned activity is already in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   <activity
      android:name=".com.solinpromex.casajuventudtrescantos.Calendario_Agenda_Activity"
      android:label="Agenda">          
 </activity>
```

and it is inside the  tag

Any help is welcome...

Comment: Your package name starts with a dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must either remove leading dot from `android:name` or change the name to not include package name:

> android:name
>
> The name of the class that implements the activity, a
> subclass of Activity. The attribute value should be a fully qualified
> class name (such as, "com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity").
>
> **However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for example, ".ExtracurricularActivity"), it is appended to
> the package name specified in the  element.**

[Docs here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm)